# How to process file paths in Emacs?

Tags: bash, emacs, save, elisp

I want to create a function that will take buffer-file-name get repo name and based on that name scp to specific server. (I don't want to use tramp because it's slow, I prefer to work locally and scp)

So far I have this:

```el
(setq save-project '(("~/projects/Repo/" .
                      (lambda ()
                        ;; run bash command in background
                        (async-exec-command "???????")))))

(defun save-project-file ()
  (interactive)
  (let* ((path (vc-find-root buffer-file-name ".git"))
         (pair (assoc path save-project)))
    (if (not (null pair))
          (funcall (cdr pair)))))

(add-hook 'after-save-hook 'save-project-file)
```

But I don't know how to create string:

```
scp <PATH without root> user@server:~/place/<PATH>
```

I can use format with `"scp %s user@server:~/place/%s"` but how can I get file without root and directory without root and filename?

Comment: what is the async-exec-command function you are using? I can't find reference to it in emacs

Comment: @JasonLewis It's mine function, it use `start-process` and `set-process-sentinel` to call shell command without blocking Emacs.

Comment: https://github.com/magnars/s.el could be of use for manipulating strings although it does't appear to have functions specific to manipulating file paths

Comment: @JasonLewis thanks, I was looking for `string-match` and `replace-match` couldn't find then in Emacs docs in strings.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question, but have you looked at the `file-relative-name` function? `(file-relative-name "/foo/bar/baz/quux" "/foo/bar") ==> "baz/quux"`

Comment: @JonO. thanks `(file-relative-name path (file-truename (vc-git-root path)))` is much better then substring.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up with this:

```
(defun git-file-path (path)
  (let* ((root (file-truename (vc-git-root path)))
         (filename (file-name-nondirectory path))
         (filename-length (length filename)))
    (let ((chunk (file-relative-name path root)))
      (substring chunk 0 (- (length chunk) filename-length)))))
```

and format that create a command:

```
(format "scp %s user@server.com:~/path/%s" buffer-file-name
        (git-file-path buffer-file-name))
```

Comment: This might be of interest? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16125637/get-the-vc-root-in-emacs-lisp